# Communication between website and android app

Tags: android, database, web

I want to build a website, where the data will be saved in a data base, logical in a sql database. Also, I want to build an android app, which will take the data from the above (sql) data base. How can I achieve it? I mean how can I manage the communication between the website and the android app. In past, I have create website with php and sql and also I have build android apps, but now I want to achieve the communication between them. Can I use parse platform?

Comment: you rest service to communicate between your webservices and android

Comment: you can use Json Parsing

Comment: Could you be more specific, Diva??

Comment: Check my answer @user4292106. I explained Diva's comment in-detail

Comment: Is there a way to build a resp api on android app, so my web app will request data to android app, is the inverse not app to server, is the server to app requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, without any server communication you can't use the website database in android application.

If you want to manage the communication between the website and the android app means you need a centralized server which having the data of your web/mobile applications. So, after that by using the web service methods (REST/SOAP) you can achieve the communication between them.

Comment: Ok, I understand the meaning of rest service. But, from where I start? Is it better to start from website? Could you to suggest any tutorial? It's my first  time on this and I have no idea..

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a clear cut tutorials which is suitable for your question. but you can refer this http://blog.trifork.com/2011/02/07/creating-an-android-app-for-your-website-with-spring-android-and-rest/  

this link too http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

Comment: Is there a way to build a resp api on android app, so my web app will request data to android app, is the inverse not app to server, is the server to app requests

Answer (score 0):

yeah unfortunately chrome won't let webapps use local storage on android. what you can do is create a local server (using org.apache.http package for example), let it run as a background android service, then have the website make requests to that url. Its considered hacky, but it would work. You can post whatever data you wanted the website to know about , and then get it from the website.