# How can i publish information from Android App and save them to any server and retrive them back from the server by another Android App?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm newbie for Android development. I have this project to complete for my semester but I'm confused about from where exactly i should start first!

I need to make 2 Android apps where both of apps should be connected to a central server or something. The first app should be for admin that will allow him to post information and the data will get saved to central database and the second app should be for client where the app will simply display the data that Admin has posted and this app also will refresh if any new data has posted by admin.

Please help me out guys!

Comment: here i answered the same type of question http://stackoverflow.com/a/28940990/3983054

Answer (score 0):

Create two api 1 for sending data to server through admin app                     2 for fetching the same data from server through the other app

Comment: can you elaborate about how can i create an API ? is there any API or anything like open source API that has already developed by anyone?

Comment: In which language you are creating webservices

Comment: well bro i'm not sure about which one to choose. can you also please guide me for best language for web-services which can also update data in app in real time?.

Comment: PHP is easy to integrate